# HTML Site moving to the left

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, containers

I'm coding a website `http://198.175.127.18/` . After a lot of the things were working yesterday, the site just moved left. I have checked all the HTML for opened `div`'s and checked the CSS. I assume the problem lies in the container class, but I haven't figured it out after hours and hours.

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: Not sure if it's the problem but you're loading your css files between the doctype and the html tag which is way wrong. They should be loaded in the head tag.

Comment: I suspect you've edited the bootstrap css files yourself which is causing the problem here. The bootstrap css files should be left alone and you should add a new stylesheet after the bootstrap ones which contains your custom styles called main.css or whatever.

Answer (score 2):

Add `margin:0 auto` to `.container`

```
.container, .navbar-static-top .container, .navbar-fixed-top .container, .navbar-fixed-bottom .container {
width: 940px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: @Gopikrishna He has posted in the question

Comment: @Gopikrishna — Your comment would be more appropriate on the question than on this answer. It does include a URL though … the OP just forgot the include the `http://` part.

Comment: sorry guys by mistakenly i commented in the answer...

Comment: Hi @Gopikrishna, Sorry for this I was checking if the container div was loading before the css and possibly causing it to move left. It doesn't make any sense you're right

Comment: Hi @Sowmya thank you for your answer. I tried this, and it didn't really work.. Do you have any further suggestions? Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Add **margin:0 auto;** to class .container, .navbar-static-top .container, .navbar-fixed-top .container, .navbar-fixed-bottom .container

And

Add **overflow-x:hidden** to body to remove horizontal scrollbar

Comment: Hi @aratidgr8 thank you for your answer. I tried this, the horizontal scrollbar was removed, even though I am able to scroll right and left still. i don't think this would fix the problem though. Do you have any further suggestions? Thank you very much for your time

Comment: Do you guys have any other suggestions? Thanks alot